# Using Grunt or Gulp with OpsWorks

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, gruntjs, gulp, aws-opsworks

I would like to trigger Grunt or Gulp when I deploy an app on Amazon OpsWorks.
By default, the Node.js layer of OpsWorks run npm install, but not gulp, and I do not know how to write custom recipes: is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to write a recipe.

Even the Node.js layer of OpsWorks installs npm via the recipe:

opsworks-cookbooks / deploy / recipes / nodejs.rb (https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/master-chef-11.10/deploy/recipes/nodejs.rb#L20 for Chef 11.10) which reads:

```
opsworks_nodejs do
    deploy_data deploy
    app application
end
```

which is defined in:

opsworks-cookbooks / deploy / definitions / opsworks_nodejs.rb (https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/master-chef-11.10/deploy/definitions/opsworks_nodejs.rb#L9 for Chef 11.10) and does:

```
node[:dependencies][:npms].each do |npm, version|
    execute "/usr/local/bin/npm install #{npm}" do
        cwd "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to spawn Gulp from the file OpsWorks expect, i.e. `server.js`:

```
var child_process = require( "child_process" );
child_process.spawn( "./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js", 
  [ "main" ].concat( process.argv.slice( 2 ) ), {
    stdio: "inherit"
  }
);
```

and then fire the real main file (e.g. `index.js`) from Gulp.